# Google calendar missing events (desktop)

Tags: google-calendar, google-calendar-reminders

My gym's app lets me book classes and then add them to my calendar.

This works fine on my Android phone, but the items are missing when I view on desktop. I've tried manually sync'ing too but to no avail.

I've noticed that the events on my calendar (when viewing on my phone) are in a slightly different colour to events that I've added manually... this tells me they must be some other kind of event type.

I think the app refers to them as 'reminders'

Does anyone know what kind of events these are and why they won't seem to sync to my desktop calendar?

**UPDATE:**

I have two Google accounts on my phone, a personal one and a work's one.

When I view the event, at the bottom it is listed as 'My Calendar'. Also when I try to 'add people' to it, it will let me invite the email address associated with my personal calendar, but not my work's calendar (I prefer to use the latter for pretty much everything)

The events show up on my phone calendar regardless of which Google account I'm currently using... yet neither show up on the desktop versions.

I also see no icon next to the event itself, or an 'owner' of the event.

[image]

[image]

Comment: The image shows the event icon, the name is Events.... Tab on "Lower Body Blast" to open it, you should be able to see more details there

Comment: @Rubén if I tap 'lower body blast' it just takes me to the screen with the 'Events: My Calendar' on it, along with the date, description etc and the ability to 'add people'... but no mention of which calendar the event belongs to

Answer (score 1):

Nowadays it's very easy to have multiple accounts in a smart-phone and in desktop web app and it's common that people gets confused.

Besides the different types of calendar elements (event, reminder, goal, task) that can be added to a calendar, you might have multiple calendars in Google Calendar: calendars created by you, created by others and shared with you, and calendars created by others that you subscribe to them.

The first thing that you have to do is to check that you are seeing the same account in your phone and Google Calendar desktop app.

The next thing is to open the event and look for hints to identify:

1. Type. Each element type use a material-design icon. On the Google Calendar mobile app tab the + button, it will show a button for each type including the corresponding icon.
2. Owner. It might show the email address of the event owner
3. Calendar. Usually the calendars are color coded and the events that belongs to each calendar have the corresponding color

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Ive just updated my question :)